# Use "lines" command with a vector of objects in R

Tags: r, list, vector, lines, spectrum

I'm using R to analyze IR-spectras. What I'm trying to do is to make a list or vector of objects, in this case Spectras, and plot them into the same "window".
I used the command `plot(Spectrum1,...)` for the first Spectrum and the commands

```
lines(Spectrum2,...) 
lines(Spectrum3,...) 
...
```

for the following Spectras. This worked well, but I was wondering if I could make a list or a vector of the Spectras, like

```
Spectras <- c(Spectrum2, Spectrum3,...)
```

or

```
Spectras <- list(Spectrum2, Spectrum3,...)
```

and plot them in one command line, like:

```
lines(Spectras,..)
```

In case of a list, R says

> 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

If I do it with the `c()` command it just plots the Spectras one behind another.

Some ideas, how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `list` and then `lapply` or `plyr::l_ply` functions. If list of spectra is called "Spectra" with each component a matrix or data frame with columns x and y:

```
lapply(Spectra, lines)
```

Or

```
plyr::l_ply(Spectra, lines)
```

Alternatively, use ggplot2:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("plyr")
SpecDf <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", Spectra))
SpecDf$SpectrumNumber <- rep(1:length(Spectra), plyr::laply(Spectra, nrow))
ggplot(SpecDf, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = SpectrumNumber)) + geom_line()
```